# Reacting to ipcMain events in Spectron

Tags: typescript, electron, spectron, ipcmain

I have an electron application that first starts a launcher window (in a renderer process) that starts several background services. After those background services started successfully it sends `"services-running"` on its `ipcRenderer` back to the main process which in turn reacts to that event by closing the launcher window and starting the main application window. The event is of course received by `ipcMain.on('services-running',...)`

I unit tested all the handlers separately so those are fine and now I want to integration test the events that pass through `ipcMain`.

This is how my integration test looks at the moment:

```
import { Application } from 'spectron';
import * as electron from "electron";
import { expect } from 'chai';
import * as chai from 'chai';
import * as chaiAsPromised from 'chai-as-promised';

let app: Application;

global.before(() => {
    app = new Application({
        path: "" + electron,
        args: ["app/main.js"],
        env: {
            ELECTRON_ENABLE_LOGGING: true,
            ELECTRON_ENABLE_STACK_DUMPING: true,
            NODE_ENV: "integrationtest"
        },
        startTimeout: 20000,
        chromeDriverLogPath: '../chromedriverlog.txt'
    });

    chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
    chai.should();
});

describe('Application', () => {

    before('Start Application', () => {
        return app.start();
    });

    after(() => {
        if(app && app.isRunning()){
            return app.stop();
        }
    });

    it('should start the launcher', async  () => {
        await app.client.waitUntilWindowLoaded();
        return app.client.getTitle().should.eventually.equal('Launcher');
    });

    it('should start all services before timing out', async (done) => {
        console.log('subscribed');
        app.electron.remote.ipcMain.on('services-running', () => {
            done();
        });
    });

});
```

The first test works fine. The second test will fail eventually after the timeout is reached although I can see `subscribed` on the shell before the main window pops up, so the event is definitely fired.

I read in the documentation that `nodeIntegration` needs to be enabled to access the full electron api with spectron, all my renderer processes are started with `{nodeIntegration: true}` in their respective `webPreferences`. But since I am interested in the main process I think this does not apply (or at least I think it shouldn't since the main process is a node process per se).

So my main question is, how would I bind to `ipcMain` events and include those in my assertions. Also how would I know when the launcher window is closed and the "main" window has been opened?

As a bonus I have some understanding issues with the spectron api.

1. If I look at the `spectron.d.ts` the `electron` property of the `Application` is of type `Electron.AllElectron` which in turn is a `MainInterface` and directly has the `ipcMain` property. So in my understanding accessing `ipcMain` should be `app.electron.ipcMain` (which is undefined), where is that remote coming from and why is it invisible in the `spectron.d.ts`.
2. The methods on `SpectronClient` all return `Promise<void>`. So I have to `await` or `then` those. If I look at the javascript examples they chain the client statements:

```
return app.client
  .waitUntilWindowLoaded()
  .getTitle().should.equal('Launcher');
```

This doesn't work in typescript because you can't chain to a `Promise<void>` obviously,... how does that work to in js?

Comment: Have you had any luck with this yet? I'm also trying to listen to ipcMain events...

Comment: @mottosson I put in my workaround as an answer. I think it's quite a general solution on how to tackle mocking internal library stuff. Been using this approach since, also on some other projects in other languages and at the moment it still holds up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tackled the problems separately. I migrated everything to classes and use fields / constructor injection to put in all the dependencies in my classes, so I can mock them, including the things that come from electron.

```
export class LauncherRenderer implements Renderer {

    protected mongo: MongoProcess;
    protected logger: Logger;
    protected ipc: IpcRenderer;

    protected STATUS_LABEL: string = 'status-text';

    constructor() {
        this.ipc = ipcRenderer;

        this.mongo = new MongoProcess(this.ipc);

        this.logger = new Logger('launcher', this.ipc);
    }
```

Inside the class I will always use `this.ipc` when subscribing to events. For unit tests I have a `FakeIpc` class:

```
import { EventEmitter } from 'events';

export class FakeIpc {

    public emitter: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

    public send(channel: string, message?: any): void { }

    public on(event: string, listener: () => void): void {
        this.emitter.on(event, listener);
    }

    public emit(event: string): void {
        this.emitter.emit(event);
    }
}
```

When setting up the Unit tests for `LauncherRenderer` I inject the `FakeIpc` into the renderer:

```
 beforeEach(() => {
        fakeIpc = new FakeIpc();
        spyOn(fakeIpc, 'on').and.callThrough();
        spyOn(fakeIpc, 'send').and.callThrough();

        mongoMock = createSpyObj('mongoMock', ['start', 'stop', 'forceStop']);

        underTest = new LauncherRenderer();

        underTest.mongo = mongoMock;
        underTest.ipc = fakeIpc;
    });
```

This way I can spy on the ipc if the subscriptions have been done, or use the public `trigger` method to shoot ipc events and test if my class reacts correctly to it.

For integration tests I recognized I should not care about internals like events (this is done in unit tests), only about the results of those (windows closing and opening). Like this:

```
    it('should start the launcher', async () => {
        await app.client.waitUntilWindowLoaded();
        const title: string = await app.client.getTitle();
        expect(title).toEqual('Launcher');
    });
```

In the next test, I wait until the launcher dissapeared and a new window opens, that way the events must have worked or that will not happen.

```
    it('should open main window after all services started within 120s', async () => {
        let handles: any = await app.client.windowHandles();

        try {
            await Utils.waitForPredicate(async () => {
                handles = await app.client.windowHandles();
                return Promise.resolve(handles.value.length === 2);
            }, 120000);
            await app.client.windowByIndex(1);
        } catch (err) {
            return Promise.reject(err);
        }

        const title: string = await app.client.getTitle();
        expect(title).toEqual('Main Window');
    });
```

The `waitForPredicate` is merely a helper method that waits for a promise to resolve or kills the test after a timeout is reached.

```
public static waitForPredicate(
    predicate: () => Promise<boolean>,
    timeout: number = 10000,
    interval: number = 1000,
    expectation: boolean = true): Promise<void> {
        return new Promise<any>(async (res, rej) => {
            let currentTime: number = 0;
            while (currentTime < timeout) {
                // performance.now() would be nicer, but that doesn't work in jasmin tests
                const t0: number = Date.now();
                const readyState: boolean | void = await predicate().catch(() => rej());
                if (readyState === expectation) {
                    res();
                    return;
                }
                await Utils.sleep(interval);
                const t1: number = Date.now();
                currentTime += t1 - t0;
            }
            // timeout
            rej();
        });
}

public static sleep(ms: number): Promise<void> {
    if (this.skipSleep) {
        return Promise.resolve();
    }
    return new Promise<void>((res) => setTimeout(res, ms));
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! Just a question about the waitForPredicate. It looks like a neat utility. How do you implement it? Do you use setInterval() in some way to check the predicates?

Comment: @mottosson I added it :)

Comment: Super! Thanks again! =)